# h:inputText getting wrong value on chrome browser and android

Tags: android, forms, jsf, google-chrome, input

I have form where several inputText fields are there which are binded to a backing bean. Strange behavior is happening with last textfield which is showing value present in some other text field (random). If I make last textfield as outputText, then that value shift to the previous textField and outputText has correct value then.

Another noticable behavior is when form is getting loaded, it shows correct value but when it is loaded completely, it changes that value to wrong one (randome). Also, on cancel it shows correct value momentarily.

I hope this explanation makes some sense. Anyone else with same kind of problem? Please let me know, if there is any solution for this. Let me know, if more info is needed.

This is happening specifically on Android and chrome browser.

Comment: Sounds strange. You should show us the code. Any chance that you are fiddling with jsf generated ids and javascript? Btw. "Android" means the android browser?

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. Unfortunately, I cannot show the code as it is proprietary. All inputtext fields have id specified but they are present inside independent panel grids which are getting JSF generated ids. Yes, Android browser i am talking about.

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced some strange autocomplete bugs in Chrome as well which get triggered by very specific form/input names/labels. The Android stock browser uses the same Webkit browser engine (and Apple Safari also), so that explains why they have the same problem. Try updating the browsers. Note that this is not specifically related to JSF.

From the server side on, your best bet is to try to turn off the autocomplete feature by setting the `autocomplete` attribute of the input elements to `off`.

```
<h:inputText ... autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Seems there is another BalusC (with I) copying your answers and identity.

Comment: Please flag if that happens again. I was beginning to wonder if your bird tried to make its own account :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Its useful from knowledge perspective but unfortunately autocomplete="off" didn't work out. I cannot upvote your response due to less reputation :(